# Voice over Ethernet without WiFi in airplane mode

Tags: wi-fi, airplane-mode

Is it possible to make calls with an active Ethernet connection only (with an Ethernet adapter) without a mobile & WiFi connection? Effectively Ethernet-Calling, like WiFi-calling.

Comment: Theoretically yes, as long as the Wifi calling is not limited to a certain Wifi (e.g. special Wifi from mobile network provider). For Wifi calling you just need a network connection. However Ethernet via USB adapters is not very common on Android therefore I don't think that somebody will test this when developing the system firmware. Therefore it might work or not depending if you are lucky or not.

Answer (score 2):

It does work using services like Google Voice (free phone number), Hushed, or iPlum on my 2 phones (Moto G4, G7) Android 7-10.

Plugable makes a Micro-USB ethernet adapter ($14) that works with Android devices or a plain USB ethernet adapter that can be used with USB-C devices with an OTG converter ($5) to make many Android tablets and phones work. They maintain a list of tested devices on their site. Device Compatability Chart: [AX88772 Compatibility List USB2-OTGE100 : USB2-OTGE100](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSco-zj9gT0LZKYCKEK0DnAuQJMZ8wppuIMLco87LbhQrD2G02jXPy1JcGvewx1GzKMS9BZVhqERok-/pubhtml)

The issue is you must use a third-party app like those mentioned, *not* the phone app that comes with the phone. That means you must have a second number associated with the app to call. If you don't care about letting Google listen to your calls, Google Voice is free. True ethernet calling may be coming in Android 11. WiFi calling is available on some phones now and this may allow true ethernet calling from the native phone app—it depends on your carrier. I am testing this option using RedPocket soon.

Comment: Do you have any source for the claim that Ethernet calling may be coming with Android 11?